# Dropdown menu not closing when clicking outside

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown

I made a header which when user clicks on a navigation button a dropdown menu appears. Now I want when user clicked everywhere of the page, it closes.

My context provider:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const StateContext = createContext();

const initialDialogsState = {
  settings: false,
  notifications: false,
  profile: false,
};

export const ContextProvider = ({  }) => {

  const [isclicked, setisclicked] = useState(initialDialogsState);

  const notificationBarRef = useRef(null);
  const settingsPanelRef = useRef(null);
  const profileBarRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const closeBars = (e) => {
      console.log(isclicked);
      if (
        (notificationBarRef.current &&
          isclicked.notifications &&
          !notificationBarRef.current.contains(e.target)) ||
        (profileBarRef.current &&
          isclicked.profile &&
          !profileBarRef.current.contains(e.target))
      ) {
        console.log("runned");
        // handleClick("notifications", false);
        // handleClick("settings", false);
        // handleClick("profile", false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", closeBars);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", closeBars);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (clicked, value = true) => {
    setisclicked({ ...initialDialogsState, [clicked]: value });
    console.log("setting " + clicked + ": " + value);
  };

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider
      value={{
        isclicked,
        setisclicked,
        handleClick,,
        notificationBarRef,
        settingsPanelRef,
        profileBarRef,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

My header component:

```
const Header = () => {
  const {
    setActiveMenu,
    isclicked,
    handleClick,
    notificationBarRef,
    profileBarRef,
  } = useStateContext();


  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between p-2 md:ml-2 md:mr-0 relative">
      
...

      <div className="flex">
        <NavButton
          func={() => handleClick("settings")}
          icon={<IoMdSettings />}
        />
        <NavButton
          func={() => handleClick("notifications")}
          icon={<RiNotification3Line />}
        />
        <div
          className="flex items-center bg-gray-200 dark:bg-secondary-dark-bg bg-opacity-70 ml-2 gap-2 cursor-pointer p-1 py-0 rounded-lg"
          onClick={() => handleClick("profile")}
        >
          <img
            className="rounded-full w-8 h-8"
            alt="User Avatar"
            src={UnknownUser}
          />
          <NavButton
            className="-mr-2"
            func={() => {}}
            icon={<MdKeyboardArrowDown />}
          />
        </div>
        {isclicked.notifications && (
          <div ref={notificationBarRef}>
            <NotificationBar />
          </div>
        )}
        {isclicked.profile && (
          <div ref={profileBarRef}>
            <ProfileBar />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

`NotificationBar` and `ProfileBar` are only jsx components

My problem is that `isclicked.profile` or `isclicked.notifications` never becomes `true` and are always `false`.

When `handleClick` is called, console log says it is setting to `true`.

Printing the value of `isclicked` after opening a menu at first is `false` but from second time to later, will be `true`